# Add sum from another method

Tags: java, methods, sum

This program is supposed to add the sum of the sequence 4 5 6 7 8 9=39.

I have done exactly as I usually do when I want to add sums, but for some reason this method returns the wrong number every single time. Here is the code:

```
public class Uppgift2_6a 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int summa=sum (4, 6 );
        System.out.print(summa);

    }

    public static int sum (int tal1, int antal )
    {

        for(int i=1; i<=antal; i++ )
        {

            tal1 = tal1+i;


        }
        return tal1;
    }

}
```

Is there something I have done in the wrong way when I'm calling the method from the main? Any answer would be very appreciated.

Comment: loop should be `for(int i=tal1+1; i<tal1 + antal; i++ )`

Comment: This code basically says the same thing? If you remove tal1 from the first and second condition, you have the same code as the one i wrote

Comment: @mackanmorre, kindly have a look at my one line solution. You need not iterate through the loop

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry, that comment was not meant for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code need a temp variable to saving the result, and the code should be like this:

```
public static int sum (int tal1, int antal ){
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0; i<antal; i++ ){
        result+= tal1+i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks boss! Exactly what I was looking for :) Answer accepted!

Comment: @mackanmorre Not at all. you need introduce a temp variable to saving the result.

Comment: yeah that is the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You assign `tal1`, rather than computing a sum in a separate variable.

You can fix your method and make it work, or [use math to compute the same number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) in one go:

```
return (antal)*(2*tal+antal-1)/2;
```

Comment: good job. and up-votes. your formula is ok,  but the OP lost the opportunity to learning the loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Artihmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

To get the sum, simply do

```
sum = (first term + last term) * (number of terms) / 2
```

Therefore, don't use <s>`int summa=sum (4, 6 );`</s>

Simply do `int summa = (4 + 9) * 6 / 2`
answer = 13`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is incorrect, if I understand your problem correctly. You need to add the first 6 numbers, from 4. Thus, this should suffice

```
for(int i=tal1+1; i<tal1 + antal; i++ ){
    tal1 = tal1+i;
}
```

It starts at `tal1+1` and runs till the next `antal` numbers, by doing `i<tal1 + antal`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static int sumOfSeries(int tal1, int antal )
{
    int lowerBound = tal1;

    for(int i=lowerBound+1; i<=antal; i++ )
    {

        tal1 = tal1+i;


    }
    return tal1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You need another variable which is total to add the tal1 to that total. Secondly, you should add 1 to the tal1 instead of i so that the tal1 variable will increase by 1 not by i.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for a [recursive](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/) approach, as an alternative:

```
public static int sum( int tal1, int antal) {
    int res = 0;
    if(tal1 <= antal) {
        int tal1 += sum(tal1+1, antal);
        res = tal1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Sure, there is no absolute need for it, but it's always interesting and worth to think about it.